# Ruby on Rails Issue with loading controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After doing fresh installation of ruby, ruby gems and rails ... I created a new application and then started it ...

I can successfully see "Welcome Aboard page" when I access http://localhost:3000/

but when I try to click on "About your application’s environment" it tries to fetch data from http://localhost:3000/rails/info/properties ...it keeps on showing the "loading symbol" in firebug but doesn't get any response.

Same is the issue with any new controller I create. Page keeps on loading but doesn't get any response ... it doesn't even show any error message.

Any help ?

Thanks,
Ami

Comment: Please post the whole log from your rails server.

Answer (score 0):

you will get the answer from the Rails log in your_rails_app/log/

Comment: It says nothing but  : Started GET "/rails/info/properties" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-07 23:04:37 +1000

Comment: any help ? I just can't start learning RoR without fixing this issue :(